# How to choose which number type operator to use in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

This code gives me the "Implicit conversion from Double to Decimal" error because the division operator " / " automatically links to the Double structure instead of the Decimal structure:

```
    Dim a As Integer 
    Dim b As Integer 
    Dim c As Decimal

    c = a / b
```

You can get around this by simply converting the result into a Decimal:

```
    c = CDec(a / b)
```

Or by converting one of the Integers into a Decimal, causing it to use the Decimal operator:

```
    c = a / CDec(b)
```

Or you can just directly call the Decimal.Divide function:

```
    c = Decimal.Divide(a, b)
```

However, it would be a lot easier to just have it select the Decimal division operator from the beginning. How do I do that?

Edit: To clarify, I am trying to make it so that the result of (a / b) always returns a Decimal instead of a Double

Comment: Are you sure about this? The [VB docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx) say that "Before division is performed, any integral numeric expressions are widened to `Double`".

Comment: As @Hassan pointed out you are always performing `Double` division when using integral types. Doing so of course causes the return value to be a `Double`. There is no way you can change it other than converting/casting (like you've already shown us) or turn each operand a `Decimal` prior to the division operation.

Comment: For starters your posted code works - as in your declarations. That code does not result in an implicit conversion error. So what are you actually asking?

Comment: @Darren: always use `Option Strict`. Then you get: _"Error BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Decimal'"_

Comment: @Seam: in my opion `Decimal.Divide` is the best option you have here

Comment: @Sean: What is the expected result? Do you want to truncate decimal places, so perform integer division? Then you use the wrong operator, use `c = a \ b` instead.

Comment: @Tim: I need floating-point division, not integer division. So (5 / 10) = 0.5

Comment: @SeanStephens: there is no other answer than use `Decimal.Divide` or live with casting because there is no decimal division operator in .NET that works with two integers. Note that always first the right side is evalauted and then the result will be assigned to the variable. The compiler will not look at the variable and then decides to interpret the right side in a different way. A division of two integers results in a `Double`. Period.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: For what reasons would it be better to use `Decimal.Divide` instead of converting the final result using `CDec(a / b)`?

Comment: It is a pretty appropriate warning, this code doesn't give you the benefits of Decimal at all.  The math is still done with binary numbers, not decimal numbers.  So you are kinda fooling yourself that you'll get a more predictable outcome.  This is turtles all the way down, if you want the precision of a Decimal result then all numbers have to be Decimal, from start to finish.